# docker client daemon access remote swarm `1.12.1` manager

Tags: docker, tls1.2, docker-swarm

I'm trying to connect to a Manager with swarm version `1.12.1` from the docker client:

```
$ docker -H tcp://MY_MANAGER_1_IP:2377 info
```

I got the following error message:

```
Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Anyone has idea, thank you in advance.

Comment: is your docker daemon running? `sudo service docker status`

Comment: @Farhad, it is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrated docker swarm in 1.12 is managed via the docker host, not via the swarm port as you would have done before in the standalone swarm product (which you can still install in a 1.12 environment if you wish). Connect to the docker host as you always have, and manage it via `docker swarm`, `docker service`, and `docker node` commands.

The port you open for the integrated swarm isn't for the docker API, it's for traffic between swarm managers and workers. To see the info on the swarm, the `docker info` on the swarm manager will include some details, and `docker node` will give a status of managers and workers. Note that this also means you cannot submit jobs to the integrated swarm with a `docker -H ... run ...` command, you must use the new `docker service` commands to manage containers in the new swarm.

For remote access to any docker host, which would let you run API commands from another machine, see the [docs on securing the Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) which is a procedure to enable TLS and setup the daemon to listen for external traffic instead of using the docker.sock socket.

Comment: thx a lot. So there is no way that I can launch the service outside swarm nodes as before by using `docker -H` ?

Comment: See the last paragraph, you can configure the docker host on your managers for remote access, and then on remote machines connect with a certificate to run `docker service` commands.

Comment: thx, I got it works, as I just work on a development environment, i simply disable the TLS with `--tls=false` in docker daemon on swarm manager node. While it is better settting up TLS for production.

Comment: It's better to use TLS anywhere, opening that port without a certificate exposes the machine to remote root access with no password required. Anyone with network access can run a docker API to mount the host filesystem as a volume with the root user in the container to access it.